# Anomalía en partida de bautismo de 1605

Tags: ortografía, historia, identificación-de-término

Os muestro a continuación la partida de nacimiento de Francisco de Yniesta Martínez, antepasado directo mío (11 generaciones) nacido en Tobarra, provincia de Albacete, en febrero de 1605:

[image: Partida de nacimiento]

Las partidas bautismales de la época me resultan muy interesantes de leer, porque me encanta ver cómo ha ido variando el lenguaje a lo largo de los años. Por ejemplo, el uso de "mill" en vez de "mil". Sin embargo, esta partida tiene algo que no había visto en ninguna otra. Y no, no me refiero a la caligrafía exquisita (normalmente me cuesta horrores descifrarlas). Fijaos en la quinta línea:

> ...hijo de Francisco de Andújar, ????? de Francisco de Yñesta...

La palabra marcada con interrogaciones no conseguía descifrarla. Pensaba que sería "digno" (no tiene sentido) o "dicho" (la h la escribe diferente, se puede ver en la línea seis en "Cathalina"), hasta que vi que en la segunda línea se menciona el "dominguo de la quincuagésima". Luego la frase queda así:

> ...hijo de Francisco de Andújar, diguo de Francisco de Yñesta...

Vamos, que el cura se equivocó y corrigió el nombre del padre sin realizar tachones. Aquí entonces me viene la pregunta. **¿Por qué usar la sílaba "guo" para lo que siempre he visto escrito como "go"?** Se me ocurren tres alternativas:

- Que sea una falta de ortografía del cura. Por entonces la escritura no estaba homogeneizada, y las palabras alteraban su ortografía según el cura que rellenara la partida. Aunque debo decir que esa sílaba no me suena de haberla visto así en ningún otro sitio.
- Que por entonces realmente sí se acostumbrara a escribir nuestra sílaba "go" como "guo", y no sea una falta de ortografía.
- La que se me antoja más remota, es que las palabras en realidad se pronunciaran tal y como las estamos viendo escritas, con una "u" de más que luego desapareció.

¿Alguien puede resolver este misterio?

**Bonus:** En la tercera línea, ¿pone "Hebrero" como nombre del mes? ¿Otra falta de ortografia o una forma antigua de "febrero"? Tampoco la había visto nunca...

Comment: *Diguo* es atestiguado como forma de *decir*, pero el diptongo *uo* no sobrevivió frente a la *o* simple, seguramente por ser este primero diptongo poco común en castellano.  La *f* antes de convertirse en *h* muda se aspiraba (cosa que sigue en algunas regiones de España) y no era infrecuente que escritores no sabían muy bien si una palabra comenzaba con F o un sonido aspirado (entonces representado con H).  Algunas palabras, obviamente como *febrero*, al final quedaron con el sonido original, pero la mayoría perdieron aquel sonido.

Comment: Sólo agregar que Corominas menciona _hebrero_ como una forma popular. Por ejemplo, [aquí](https://archive.org/stream/elcuerdoloco00vega#page/96/mode/2up) la usa Lope de Vega (verso 2177).

Comment: ¡Sí! [_hebrero_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=K4XYC2w|K4bpc8Q) la recoge el DRAE como nombre masculino desusado para febrero.

Comment: @fedorqui muy buena, ni se me había pasado por la cabeza mirarlo en el DRAE.

Comment: Noten el cambio, en la raíz de algunas palabras, de *f* en *h*, como *filio* en *hijo*, *farina* en *harina*.  Fíjense también en esta transcripción de un documento de 1568 [partida de defunción](https://www.genealogieonline.nl/en/rodriguez-lopez-y-uribe-senior/I72.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basándome en el comentario de guifa, buscando en el [CORDE](http://www.rae.es/recursos/banco-de-datos/corde) se encuentran hasta 14 ocurrencias de *diguo*, en ejemplos como:

> [...] **diguo** yo considerando el largo tyenpo que a [...]
>
> [...] **diguo** que non es necesario buscar otras muxas causas [...]
>
> [...] como estas dos et yo uos **diguo** que si asi la certades uos asi bien como estas [...]

Las ocurrencias son todas de textos de los siglos XV y XVI. Tampoco es de extrañar que los cambios en la ortografía no llegaran hasta más tarde a los pueblos de la España profunda. También recoge el CORDE apariciones de *dominguo*:

> Facta carta en el mes de ffebrero, **dominguo** dia de Carnestueltas, era e tresientos e dizenueu.

Aunque en este caso las apariciones son para los siglos XIII y XIV. En todo caso, las apariciones de *dominguo* para el siglo XIV son tan solo 3, que comparadas con las 302 de "domingo" hacen pensar que pueda ser simplemente una falta de ortografía, aunque por entonces no se pueda llamar como tal, dado que la ortografía no estaba regulada. También es posible, como dice guifa, que se permitieran ambas formas, pero el diptongo "uo" se fuera perdiendo en favor de la "o" simple. Las apariciones de "digo" en el CORDE también son mucho más numerosas que las de *diguo* en aquella época.

Sobre *hebrero*, como dijo fedorqui aún sigue recogido en el DRAE:

> **[hebrero](http://dle.rae.es/?id=K4bpc8Q)**
>
> 1. m. desus. febrero.