# In 1818 California a priest calls a young godfather "Mocho". Why?

Tags: nombres-propios, religión

In Spanish Alta California the church held notable power. Immigrants who wanted to get ahead in society would undergo Catholic baptism, helping them qualify to marry or acquire land.

In 1818 a recently baptized foreigner in his early twenties served as godparent. The baptismal register is online but difficult to search in the [Early California Population Project Database](http://missions.huntington.org). The officiating priest recorded that the godfather was at *diez meses de haver abradado de la religion Catolica* (*abradado* could be a transcription error for *abracado* or *abrazado*, synonyms, or *abrasado*).

The priest also inserted the adjectival or titular term *Mocho* in front of the godfather's name. According to the modern dictionaries I have at hand, this word suggests someone missing a limb -- though I don't think the guy was missing any body parts -- or someone acting falsely pious. Coming from a priest, this sounds like being an insult, and dare I say un-Christian. It could also be a term of art with other connotations.

What was the priest indicating to future readers of the baptismal register by marking the young man as *Mocho*?

**APPENDIX. The database record in question:**

> Mission: San Carlos de Borromeo
>
> Number: 03076
>
> Baptism Date: 7 Apr 1818
>
> Birthdate: 6 Apr 1818 "nacida del dia anterior como a las dos de la tarde"
>
> Location: Capilla del Real Presidio
>
> Ethnicity: Razon
>
> Type: +
>
> Sex: F
>
> Name: Pliego, Ysidora
>
> Father: Pliego, Narciso from Jalapa en la nueva España, maestro de tela[...]os en la mision de la Soledad
>
> Mother: Briones, Agueda from Monterrey citado
>
> Officiant: Amorós, Juan
>
> Godparents: Buelna, Maria Hilaria; Mocho Bol[...], Jose

and then with regard to the latter:

> Godparent name: Mocho Bol[...], Jose
>
> Godparent type: Padrino
>
> Godparent origin: Ruso, nacion de
>
> Godparent comments: "diez meses de haver abradado de la religion Catolica"

The Russian was Jose Antonio Bolcof.

Comment: I found in Google books another case, where they say _Hijo de Juan Caballero y María Sánchez, vecinos de Castro-**mocho**_. It could be that on those years missing a limb was relevant enough to be noted there? Note also that the [diccionario de americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=yyUan3vZvx0Axvy3qk0|9jkniYt3yx0Ar7KI93l|IgfhfGOlwx0AkKpfXKn) registers many meanings for this word. I find specially relevant the one from Mexico: _Referido a persona, que exagera en los actos de devoción religiosa. fest._ That is, _someone who exaggerates in acts of religious devotion_.

Comment: @fedorqui I agree. The "missing a limb" meaning does not apply to Mexico, as does the "religiously exaggerated" meaning. Bear in mind that this is the **current** meaning, maybe in the first years of the XIX century it meant something else in the religious context.

Comment: If you have the image you could upload the relevant part so we could see it, maybe we notice something else that could give us a clue. You can see an example in [my question here](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17874/12637).

Comment: Maybe it is related to his origin: see [Mocho' language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mocho%E2%80%99_language) in Wikipedia. Mocho’ or Mototzintleco is a language of the western branch of Mayan languages spoken in the Mexican state of Chiapas. Nowadays it is a moribund language with barely 30 speakers, but maybe in the beginning of the XIX century there were more speakers.

Comment: It also could be a last name. A short internet search gave that there are some people with this last name, plus this site that mentions some history of the family. http://www.heraldrysinstitute.com/cognomi/Mocho/Spain/idc/644010/lang/es/

Comment: Yes. It is a last name. The origin is Spain however it is the 45144º more common last name.... so, no common at all. See here http://www.xn--apellidosespaa-2nb.com/apellido/mocho.html Looks like the place it is more common is in the Ourense province where it is also very uncommon. Perhaps @fedorqui or Carlos can find out more about that.

Comment: @DGaleano the INE (Spanish National Institut of Statistics) just reports 38 occurrences in the whole country. Find the tool in http://www.ine.es/apellidos/formGeneralresult.do

Comment: @CarlosAlejo unfortunately the database does not contain images, so all I have is the text. (Imagery of the original is on microfilm somewhere with the Mormons.)

Comment: @DGaleano in this case, "Mocho" is not the man's surname, which is given separately. As far as I know, as a Russian he had no connection to Chiapas.

Comment: AaronBrick Russian? This may be an interesting add-on to the question. As @CarlosAlejo suggested, could you attach an image so that we can see if there is some extra information worth checking?

Comment: @fedorqui there is no imagery in the online Project, but if you follow the link, Enter the site, select Godparent, then specify the Name "Mocho", you will find record SC #03076. The godfather's true surname is Bolcof. Getting the image would mean renting a roll of microfilm from the Mormon genealogical operation.

Comment: The provided link takes you to a web page that needs a login (username/password) that we do not know. Maybe you do not have the image, but surely you have access to the text. Could you copy and paste the complete text? Besides, you could try searching in [FamilySearch](https://familysearch.org/search) for that register, if you find it provide the link and we will be able to help you better. FamilySearch is also a service provided by the mormons.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo, you can put in any name and email to access the ECPPD. If the record had been one solid chunk of text I would have pasted it in the first place, but it is presented as several dozen short fields, mostly empty. As I mentioned, the Mormons have the record on microfilm, but not indexed on their web site.

Comment: It was my assumption that the proper names of the baby and priest were irrelevant to this question, but if not, they were Isidora Pliego Briones and Juan Amorós.

Comment: Aaron: these useful details from the website should be moved into the question itself, so that it is easier for us to use it. I was already able to access the DB (with a random username/pwd) but now I struggle to get the results you mention. What fields did you select and with what values?

Comment: Hi folks, it took some organizing, but I pasted above the contents of all the non-trivial fields in the database records. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Not related to the question, but I found information about [her death in 1850](https://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GRid=126227563).

Comment: [More context](https://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=gr&GRid=91359681): "Josef Bolcof was born on Russia's Kamchatka Peninsula about 1795. He sailed to Alta California [...] in 1815. He converted to Roman Catholicism and was baptized "José Antonio Bolcof" [...] in 1817. José married María Candida Castro y Amador [...] in 1822. He was _alcalde_ (mayor) at Branciforte in 1834, 1839-42, and 1845-46. [...] José served as a _juez de paz_ (justice of the peace) in 1842. José and Candida became U.S. citizens [...] in 1848. José Bolcof died in California about 1866."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll add my $0.02 MXN

although there is no documentation to refer to, being a very colloquial expression I can confirm at least 4 current usages of the word ***Mocho*** in Mexico, particularly in Baja California (not so far from your find)

1. Being overly religious or exaggerating on the practice of the catholic faith, (widely used nowadays)
2. **Mocho**, (*lisado*) as in missing a limb. it is used to describe those who have lost most of an extremity, such as an arm or a leg, as opposed to '*cojo*' or '*manco*' when missing a hand or a leg from the knee down, It is interesting to note how the word comes to be used to describe amputees, herein lies the key:
3. '**Mocho**', (*incompleto*) missing a part, as the subject and action of the verb:
4. '**Mochar**' (*cortar*). You may not be "**Mocho**" yourself, but you may have "***El dedo Mocho***" (missing a finger). Why are you missing a finger? ***"Me lo **moché** por accidente trabajando"*** Applies not only to bodily harm, but to objects and things that have been cut and are thus incomplete:

*No vimos lo mejor de la pelicula, le **mocharon** el final!*

We didn't see the best part of the movie, it was cut at the end!

*El ingeniero encargó que **mocharamos** esos arboles a la mitad, para que no hagan contacto con el cableado de alta tension*

The engineer ordered us to cut those trees in half, to avoid them making contact with the high tension wires.

Another usage of the verb form of **Mocho** is '*to share*' or to have shared something valuable, an allegory of cutting oneself and giving away something dear and close to you (such as an arm and a leg ...bingo!) and to give it away without asking for compensation in return, for the good of others. If you *sell* your kidney, it doesn't apply. If you however *donate* your kidney, "***Te mochaste con un riňón***"

Also this is not limited to bodily parts. all too often, people will ask for freebies **"Oiga, *Mochese* con los refrescos**" "Give us some soft drinks" if you agree, they wont pay for the soft drinks, because "**Te mochaste**"

An abstract example, that happened to me recently "**Profe, *Móchese* con un punto; para irnos de vacaciones sin preocuparnos por el examen**" (I teach calculus at a local high school, and my pupils were under the impression that I would just give them a free point on their terms, if they asked so they could enjoy their spring break. Needless to say, **NO Me *moché*!**

All of these, in current use; even amongst well educated groups.

---

My theory:
It could be that this person shared his wealth as was the custom for godfathers at the time, they literally threw money in the air (*bolo*) so kids would all come running and have fun trying to gather the most coins from el padrino.

Or if he was not missing a limb, perhaps he was missing a finger. In the historical context, a godfather had actual responsibilities towards his "ahijados" and had to vouch for them in addition to their parents in certain circumstances, so being a foreigner recently eligible to be a godfather, perhaps the priest made the annotations so as to identify him in a time where taking a photograph was either impossible or a very expensive and painstaking affair.

Comment: The concept of mocharse you describe is fascinating, thanks for the extended discussion. The NTC Chicano Spanish dictionary defines it as "mooching off of" someone (a word with a Germanic root). I'd be surprised if the word were in use at that place and time, but who knows. Yes, he could have been missing an arm or finger.

Answer (score 1):

The first possibility in hlecuanda's answer does seem the most likely. No source of which I am aware says that the subject was missing an appendage. According to Maynard Geiger, Amorós had been a Franciscan priest longer than Bolcoff had been alive. Apparently he was triggered, adding the explanatory detail that Bolcoff's conversion had taken place only ten months before. I conclude that Amorós doubted Bolcoff's sincerity as a Catholic.

Comment: Thanks for posting an update.  I'm not sure if there's official guidance about this, but I've been encouraged on other SE sites to post my update within the question itself, at the bottom.