# Reconocer una palabra manuscrita de 1824

Tags: escritura, correspondencia, identificación-de-término

Aquí va una frase de la mano de Fr. Gil y Taboada, sacerdote franciscano en California, de 1824. Se quejó de alguien que le solicitaba dinero. Aún no conseguí leer una palabra, que por las letras superescritas parece abreviada.

Sin tener más ejemplares del propio Gil y Taboada, creo que una terminal y superescrita -es quiere decir -ciones.

"Este me reinsta con repetidas _______.":

[image]

Comment: Alcanzo a leer algo como "*Éste me reinsta con repetidas cartas.*" Realizando una búsqueda en la red, no encontré ninguna información acerca de esta frase en algún manuscrito asociado al sacerdote Gil y Taboada. Esto es simplemente lo que alcanzo a distinguir.

Comment: @Flxtr en un principio parece que podría ser "cartas", pero me extraña el hecho de que en la escritura las eses parecen bastante consistentes. Mira cómo están escritas en "rein_s_ta" y al final de "repetida_s_". Si fuera "cartas" veríamos una ese similar. El OP sugiere que es una abreviatura, podríamos tratar de tirar por ahí. (Ojo, no descarto que sea "cartas", que también podría ser un error de escaneo.)

Comment: @CarlosAlejo sí, tienes razón respecto a las letras "*s*" y como bien dices, un mayor contexto es posible que nos dé más claridad.

Comment: +1 a cartas ...

Comment: ¡Hombre, pero si es Bolcoff, [nuestro viejo amigo](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19320/12637)!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creo si se analiza con un poco de cuidado la ortografía, lo más razonable es pensar que la palabra es ***cartas***.

[image]

La primera letra es una "**c**", podemos ver claramente el mismo estilo en 'contestado':
[image]

La segunda letra es una '**a**', con la misma caligrafía que en 'nadie':

[image]

La tercera, 'r', con el mismo estilo que "reinsta" pero alargando los trazos de los extremos por estar la letra entre otras dos en vez de al principio:

[image]

Las siguientes, "t" y "a", se leen correctamente. 
La última "s" recuerda un poco a la "s" de "Luisito". 
[image]

Obviamente el trazo no está claro, pero hay que notar que en otras palabras del texto también se aprecian trazos 'extra' o de forma descuidada, por ejemplo la "t" de "reinsta":

[image]

Cuadra mejor que ninguna otra opción con el contexto semántico.

Comment: Es una buena respuesta, y estoy de acuerdo contigo en que es la opción que mejor cuadra. Me sigue extrañando el hecho de que si es "cartas", la "s" final no se parezca a la "s" final de la palabra anterior, "repetidas", me hace seguir buscando más opciones. ¿Podrías colaborar en la respuesta _wiki_ para tratar de descifrar todo el texto?

Comment: No comprendo como el final estaria superescrito para escribir _cartas_. Seria _cartaciones_?

Comment: @AaronBrick no encuentro ninguna referencia en CORDE a cartaciones...

Comment: @CarlosAlejo No sé si entiendo lo que comentas de que la "s" no aparezca al final de la palabra anterior... Yo leo "repetidas" claramente, esa "s" al final sí que es con la misma caligrafía que el resto del texto. Gracias for el comentario y por supuesto que colaboraré en el wiki :)

Comment: @RocíoGarcíaLuque me refería a que la s final de "cartas" no se parece a la s final de "repetidas".

Comment: Sigo algo incómodo por la superescritura, pero lo acepto.

Answer (score 3):

Justo como lo decía en los comentarios, podría asegurar que es:

> Éste me reinsta con repetidas cartas

Esto solo como complemento a la [respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20112/14481) de [Rocío](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/2800/roc%C3%ADo-garc%C3%ADa-luque) que nos hizo favor de analizar letra por letra. Ahora, analicemos la letra "*s*" del fragmento *"..mi súplica...*:

[image]

Con la "*s*" de *...cartas*:

[image]

Pareciera ser que solo existe una pequeña variación, esto se puede dar por diferentes motivos, pero sin duda creo que esa es la palabra que hace falta.

Comment: Muy buena esa apreciación, @Flxtr. Voto arriba.

Answer (score 2):

De repente pude leer [*cuestaciones*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Bb1kPkk) (RAE: *Petición o demanda de limosnas para un objeto piadoso o benéfico*).

No voy a aceptar ninguna respuesta hasta ver ahí algún consenso.

Comment: Es una opción muy buena, sin duda, pero yo juraría que después de la _c_ va una _a_. Me resulta difícil ver ahí un _ue_.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos a poner una respuesta *community wiki* en la que poder escribir el texto completo, dado que hay algunas palabras de los alrededores que tampoco entiendo, a ver si entre todos lo sacamos.

Nota: entre corchetes los textos que sean duda. Quien pueda confirmarlo que los quite.

```
Mi querido Luisito: ni  
me has contestado á  
mi suplica sobre Bol.  
coff. Este me reinsta  
con repetidas ?????  
Yo no puedo ser fiador
de nadie porque es contra  
mi instituto.
```

Comment: _¿No puedo ser fiador?_

Comment: @fedorqui creo que es decir que no hace ningún préstamo.

Comment: @AaronBrick sí, entiendo qué es _fiador_. En mi comentario a [la versión original](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/revisions/20111/1) sugería que esa fuera la palabra que completara la frase _?? no puedo ??? ??????_